# How to click a button by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

there is a button and now I want to click it n number of times using javascript.

```
<button id="btn"></button>
```

now I want to click it n number of times (suppose using a loop) an example please

ps:I'm new to js :)

Comment: First rule of coding: [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+click+a+button+by+using+javascript)

Comment: Do you really want to click it or do you want to invoke the action(s) that are triggered by clicking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DOM click() Method for example `document.getElementById("btn").click()`

make button clicked one time.

```
x=10;
for (i=0;i<=x;i++)
document.getElementById("btn").click();
```

Loop with clicking :)